# Flash CS5.5 for iPad turns landscape stage into portrait SWF

Tags: ios, flash, ipad

This seems pretty weird even for Adobe standards. I've set up size of the movie to be 1024x768, which is the resolution of ipad screen in landscape. The stage looks ok but when I publish the swf it goes into portrait mode.

I even used this line of code but it doesn't help.

stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);

[image: Flash IDE iPad orientation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. You should go to Publish Settings > Player Settings > Aspect ration: Landscape

Player Settings are hard to locate, it is the topmost right button (a spanner icon), next to the Player drop down menu.